# AndroidManifest.xml <uses-configuration> makes it available to 0 devices in Market?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I used to have this clause in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-configuration android:reqFiveWayNav="false"
                    android:reqHardKeyboard="false"
                    android:reqKeyboardType="nokeys"
                    android:reqNavigation="nonav"
                    android:reqTouchScreen="notouch"/>
```

As far as I know, these values mean "doesn't require anything at all". I added this clause mostly for completeness.

However, it caused my app to show that it is available to 0 devices in the Android Market console! Removing it fixes this, of course. Still, it seems like a bug as this setting should not cause anything to be excluded.

Has anyone with more experience seen such an issue, or, can spot my misunderstanding? Do these values actually cause restrictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question -- got a reply from the Android team. It looks like this is simply a bug and "notouch" is being treated at "no touchscreen at all", which is not what it is supposed to do. So, just a little bug in the platform.

Comment: how do you contact the Android team for problems like these?

Comment: Well, in our case, we are from Google so know some of them :)

Answer (score 0):

For the records, I've found that one *significant* change that solved my case. Full explanation is at [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msg/android-market/LFGAnPjFJM0/YO4qeUrTc2QJ) on Android Market Product Group.

Quick answer is remove the following `uses-feature` nodes from your manifest if present:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" />
```